# Android on device testing doesn't work anymore, used to

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testing, device

**TLDR: on device app testing doesn't work anymore, used to perfectly.**

I'm currently writing an android app, not a super complicated one, just a small one with text to get the hang of it. Since I have an old AMD cpu, I can't use the emulator, so I test on my phone. Everything worked perfectly, I could see my main menu, until I added a second java class/activity: the app builds with success, gets transfered to my phone, I get either a blank screen or it prompts me to the usual security "are you sure you want to run it?" before giving my a blank screen. I don't understand, it worked perfectly and quite well, I could use the app, type text etc, but now I can't even run it... also, when I go back on my homescreen and try to tap on my app icon, which used to work, it just spashes a blank screen, again.

I tried uninstalling my app and reinstalled it, did not work. Restarted android studio, my machine and the phone, did not work. I removed dev mode on my phone before putting it back on, same, did not work.

IDK if it's important, but since I'm learning/in the building process, all the UI elements (e.g textviews, textedits, buttons etc) are laid out BUT not all of them are referenced in the java code.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Even if an app was built successfully, it may still encounter exceptions when in use. When an exception occurs in your app, it crashes and shuts off which seems to be the behavior you are describing.  When your phone is plugged in and you run your app, you can check the debug console for any exceptions which might help you figure out what's wrong.

Is it just a blank page or does it just open then suddenly close when opened?

Comment: Console shows nothing, everything seems to be building correctly... I ran a test with a hello world project which ran fine on my phone? seems there is an error somewhere in my stuff or it is random...